# What does it mean to normalize an array?

Tags: java, arrays, normalize

I need to normalize an array that contains values between 0 to 1024 into an array that will contain values between 0-255. I am doing this in Java but I am wanting to understand what exactly does it mean to "normalize an array" rather than asking for exact code.

Comment: "Normalize an array" means to apply the process of [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization) to an array.

Comment: If it's actually up to 1023, not 1024, you can just do an integer division by 4.

Comment: @DavidWallace Doesn't fit in a 0-255 range: `1023/4 == 255.75`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - Actually, `1023/4 == 255`.  Try it.  I deliberately specified integer division.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To normalize a vector in math means to divide each of its elements
to some value V so that the length/norm of the resulting vector is 1.
Turns out the needed V is equal to the length (norm) of the vector.

Say you have this array.

`[-3, +4]`

Its length (in Euclid metric) is: `V = sqrt((-3)^2 + (+4)^2) = 5`

So its corresponding normalized vector is:

`[-3/5, +4/5]`

Its length is now: `sqrt ( (-3/5)^2 + (+4/5)^2 )` which is 1.

You can use another metric (e.g. I think Manhattan distance)
but the idea is the same. Divide each element of your array
by `V` where `V = || your_vector || = norm (your_vector)`.

So I think this is what is meant here.

See also:

http://www.fundza.com/vectors/normalize/

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalizedVector.html

Answer (score 2):

Normalize in this case essentially means to convert the value in your original scale to a value on a different scale. Something like this will do it:

```
x = origVal / 1024;
xNorm = 255 * x;
```

You will have to decide how you want to handle rounding.

So for example:

```
.5 = 512 / 1024;
127.5 = 255 * .5;
```